# RBS with SharePoint 2010 and SQL Express 2008 / 2012.

Tags: sql-server, database, rbs

My client has about 100GB of files loaded on a File Server. Initially the plan was to upload everything to SharePoint and bring everything under one hood.
They have SharePoint Foundation 2010 and SQL Express 2008. When I was assigned the project, (due to my limited knowledge and experience in SharePoint) , I told the client that the SQL express has size limit of 10GB and SQL Express 2008 does not use RBS.

They didn't have enough storage for SQL server . They wanted to make use of the File Server. That is upload file to SharePoint and delete the physical file after uploading it to SP. Since SQL 2008, does not support RBS, I dropped that idea. Later I came to know that SQL Express 2012 can use RBS. Oh no. That is , I could have used SQL Express 2012 and stored the files as blobs on the file server which is right but I didn't offer an alternative.

This made us (because of me) to upload only limited number of files from the File Server thinking that we have 10GB limit. 
Now what should I tell the client ? Do you think in future we may have problem because of the express version and 100gb worth files. Client has no plans to use SQL standard.

We also have sharepoint search implemented. Suppose I upload files all together 100gb ( includes PDF, Doc, XLS etc ) , the sharepoint search database could cross the limit of 10 GB. Do you think the search database size would've been a problem if I had used SQL Express 2008/2012

Comment: The size limits on SQL Express are the database file sizes, regardless of the application. Once your index databases reach 10GB, you cannot index more and you will encounter problems.

Comment: And how am I indexing ? By implementing SharePoint search ? Just want to clarify.

Comment: And how would you encounter the problem with the given scenarios that is only using SQL Express.

Comment: Indexing is performed by SharePoint Search. It will do that for you.

Comment: And how would I deal with it? By upgrading to SQL Server Standard or higher. I don't envisage many decent scale SharePoint scenarios (and 100GB of content in the first shoot is a medium scale situation) being possible at all on SQL Express.